# Using a Generic Table in Linq Join Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have various list type tables in the Db that populate dropdowns. I writing a Linq query to get the list data when joined to a translation table. The list type tables could be any one:

The query so far:

```
var listType = (from t1 in _context.Translations
               join s in _context.Set<T>() on t1.TranslationCode equals s.GetType().GetProperty("TranslationCode").GetValue(s, null)
               select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm struggling to set the generic type property on the join.
Error:

```
{ error = The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Translation>()
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Status>(), 
        outerKeySelector: t => t.TranslationCode, 
        innerKeySelector: s => s.GetType().GetProperty("TranslationCode").GetValue(
            obj: s, 
            index: null), 
        resultSelector: (t, s) => new TransparentIdentifier<Translation, Status>(
            Outer = t, 
            Inner = s
        ))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https: //go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information. }
```

Which I'm guessing is saying Linq can't convert into SQL. Thanks

Comment: You can't use a generic context.Set<T> ... probably you should write a query for each of your list types here.

Comment: Your expression needs to be something that could be translated to SQL, which your expression is not. As the message says, get your result to local first using something like AsEnumerable and then do the join on local data.

Answer (score 0):

Linq doesn't know how to translate .GetType()... to SQL. Get your data to local using something like AsEnumerable() and make the join there. ie:

```
var listType = (from t1 in _context.Translations.AsEnumerable()
               join s in _context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable() on t1.TranslationCode equals s.GetType().GetProperty("TranslationCode").GetValue(s, null)
               select s).FirstOrDefault();
```